# How to model MongoDB User Schema and their corresponding data?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, data-modeling

I'm creating a Google Keeper replica where a user can log in and the list of todo list for that user is stored.

I'm new to mongoDB, express, and react, and I was wondering how someone would go about doing this. Would you create a User Schema with the "list objects" or create a User Schema and a separate List schema.

I think the creating one schema would be more efficient, but when I go to update or delete a note, I don't know how I would target a specific note without an ID since the ID would be associated with the entire user schema.

Thank you!

Comment: See this document on [Model Relationships Between Documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/applications/data-models-relationships/).

Answer (score 0):

You can assign an unique id to the list entries while inserting them into the database. For example, you can use timestamp. The structure of your list items will be something like-

{ itemId: "1595488458403", value: "Do the laundry" }

As the items will be created one by one, therefore, there timestamps will be different. To create the timestamp of the present time, use--     new Date().getTime()

Here's the roadmap

1. Bring the value of the list item from your frontend to the backend. (say, "Do the laundry")
2. Define a variable "itemId" in the backend route:

   itemId = new Date().getTime()
3. While inserting the item to the user's list of to-dos, insert:

   { itemId: itemId, value: "Do the laundry" }